# How do I cover a plane in a bumpy foam material effect?

Tags: unity

I need to fill a weapon bag with foam material.

This is what it should look lik:

[image]

The material in the upper part of the bag looks like this:

[image]

I'm using HDRP.

How could I do this?

Thank you!

Edit: I have played around with Parallax Occlusion mapping, and I got [this result](https://youtu.be/aLjBPTXSCRk).

Edit2: I am not sure if I use the Pixel Displacement as it has been suggested to me.

Also, I'm not sure if I use it the correct way:

I have created a Height map and put it into the Height map slot. 
This doesn't create any effect.
I have to put the same map into the Base map slot in order to see the effect.
If I put a black image into the Base map slot or if I choose Black as the Base color, no effect is visible.

I don't understand why this is so. I think even if my Base map is black, the Shader has pixels that it can move.

This is my height map:
[image]

Edit 3: It was suggested that I should use a normal map. This doesn't look at all what I expected. The normal map was created from the Height map using an online tool:

[image]

By Philipp's answer I found out that the normal map alone is not enough.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96410/discussion-on-question-by-tmighty-how-do-i-cover-a-plane-in-a-bumpy-foam-materia).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A heightmap changes the *position* of the texels, but not their *color shade*. If you want some parts of the texture to be brighter and others darker depending on how they face the light source, then you want a normal map.

I used the texture you provided as both a normal map and a height map and created this material:

[image: result]

For the normal map image, select the import settings "Texture Type: Normal map" and switch on "Create from Grayscale". If you apply the import settings, [the texture should appear light blue](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88353/why-are-normal-maps-predominantly-blue) in the editor:

[image: normal map]

If you also want to use the same texture as a heightmap for displacement, then you need to create a copy of the image under a different name, so you can apply different import settings. It will work with the default settings, but because we only care about the brightness we don't need all 3 color channels. So you can reduce a bit of overhead by turning it into a "single channel" texture:

[image: height map]

These are my material settings. I highlighted all values which I changed from the defaults:
[image: material]

Further steps you can take to improve these textures further:

- Make both maps less "pointy"
- Add some noise to the normal map

Comment: Thank you for the lesson!! Do you suggest noise to the normal map because that would simulate pores in the foam?

Comment: @tmighty Yes, that's why.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make the foam spikes less pyramidal?

Comment: Can you please share your project somewhere? I don't seem to be able to get the same results as you do.

Comment: Can you share you project?